# Parquet conversion with complex structures

Tags: .net-core, serialization, parquet

I'm trying to create a parquet with this structure:

```
struct
   struct
      double
   list
      struct
        int
```

I'm using Parquet.NET v3.9.0.
This is the code:

```
var schema = new Schema(                    
                new StructField("struct1",
                    new StructField("struct11",
                        new DataField<double?>("double1")
                    ),
                    new ListField("list2",
                        new StructField("element",
                            new DataField<int?>("int1")
                        )
                    )
                )
            );

var table = new Table(schema)
{
    new Row(
        new Row(
            new Row(2.2),
            new Row[]
            {
                new Row(1)
            }
        )
    )
};
```

When I execute the program I have this runtime error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'Parquet.Data.Rows.Row'.
at Parquet.Data.Rows.RowValidator.Validate(Row row, IReadOnlyList`1 fields) at Parquet.Data.Rows.RowValidator.Validate(Row row, IReadOnlyList`1 fields)
at Parquet.Data.Rows.Table.Add(Row item)

However, if I comment the first struct level everything is ok:

```
var schema = new Schema(                    
                //new StructField("struct1",
                    new StructField("struct11",
                        new DataField<double?>("double1")
                    ),
                    new ListField("list2",
                        new StructField("element",
                            new DataField<int?>("int1")
                        )
                    )
                //)
            );

var table = new Table(schema)
{
    new Row(
        //new Row(
            new Row(2.2),
            new Row[]
            {
                new Row(1)
            }
        //)
    )
};
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The error says you tried to store a `Row` where a `double` was expected. The schema has two struct levels, but your code uses *three*

Comment: I have the same error with two levels.